# Nesting sql queries inside case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a SQL query where I am joining two tables and retrieving a few columns. Once this is done, based on a two fields (source table enum, id in the corresponding source table), I need to retrieve a value matching the id in the source table.

The issue is that I cannot join all the source tables, and want to do something like this:

```
Select 
  X.Col1,
  X.Col2,
  Y.Col1,
  Y.Col2,
  CASE
    WHEN Y.TableID = 4 THEN Select t4.Col1 FROM TableFour t4 WHERE t4.id = Y.FileID
    WHEN Y.TableID = 5 THEN Select t5.Col4 FROM TableFive t5 WHERE t5.id = Y.FileID
  END
FROM Table X INNER JOIN Table Y ON X.ID = Y.XID
```

I can guarantee the value being retrieved from all the source tables will be the same (i.e. nvarchar).

Nesting SQL queries inside the CASE statement doesn't seem to work, I am throwing it you guys. Any ideas with this problem?

Hope I explained the question adequately. If you are unsure, make a comment so I can clarify it.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "cannot join all the source tables", can you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: It's likely that joining to those tables introduces additional rows the OP doesn't want in the final result set...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: if subselects in CASE return at most one row, there will be no allitional rows. If not, the subselects, even if they compiled, would blow up "subquery returned more than one row". In that case the way to go is to wrap TOP 1 in CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: I agree, the setup is fragile & rather poor - I said as much in my answer, while providing an alternative for consideration.  Without a data dump, there's not much more to be said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean by "cannot join all the source tables", can you elaborate?
I would use outer joins:

```
Select 
  X.Col1,
  X.Col2,
  Y.Col1,
  Y.Col2,
  COALESCE(t4.Col1 ,t5.Col4)
  END
FROM Table X INNER JOIN Table Y ON X.ID = Y.XID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableFour t4 ON t4.id = Y.FileID AND Y.TableID = 4
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableFive t5 ON t5.id = Y.FileID AND Y.TableID = 5
```

Comment: No, the criteria inside outer join condition will not filter Y. Try out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets to encapsulate the SELECT within the CASE expression:

```
Select X.Col1,
       X.Col2,
       Y.Col1,
       Y.Col2,
       CASE
         WHEN Y.TableID = 4 THEN (Select t4.Col1 FROM TableFour t4 WHERE t4.id = Y.FileID) 
         WHEN Y.TableID = 5 THEN (Select t5.Col4 FROM TableFive t5 WHERE t5.id = Y.FileID)
       END
  FROM Table X 
  JOIN Table Y ON X.ID = Y.XID
```

...but I'd like to stress that this is a poor design choice.  You could use LEFT JOINs instead:

```
   Select X.Col1,
          X.Col2,
          Y.Col1,
          Y.Col2,
          CASE
            WHEN Y.TableID = 4 AND t4.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN t4.Col1 
            WHEN Y.TableID = 5 AND t5.Col4 IS NOT NULL THEN t5.Col4
          END
     FROM Table X 
     JOIN Table Y ON X.ID = Y.XID
LEFT JOIN TABLEFOUR t4 ON t4.id = y.fileid
LEFT JOIN TABLEFIVE t5 ON t5.id = y.fileid
```

Comment: Totally forgot about left joins, sorry guys for this n00b question. Easy fix. : )

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a function for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetVal
(@tblNum int, @FileID int)
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @return nvarchar(255);
  if @tblNum = 4 then
    Select @return=t4.Col1 FROM TableFour t4 WHERE t4.id = @FileID;
  else
    if @tblNum =5 
      Select @return=t5.Col4 FROM TableFive t5 WHERE t5.id = @FileID;
  return @return
END;
```

Then your Select just looks like:

```
Select 
  X.Col1,
  X.Col2,
  Y.Col1,
  Y.Col2,
  dbo.GetVal(Y.TableID, Y.FileID) 
FROM Table X INNER JOIN Table Y ON X.ID = Y.XID
```

Comment: Scalar UDFs are terribly slow.

Comment: This will work, but IME the performance won't scale with large loads--it's guaranteeing a correlated subquery for every row returned, when you could join to the appropriate tables once in the main query...

Comment: I agree. A UDF is a poor choice.